# Music play count tracker

Tags: music, tracking

Is there a (ideally free) cloud service that can do the following?

1. Can track music / song plays.
2. Integrate with iTunes and iOS.
3. Can import [data from last.fm](https://www.last.fm/user/MythOfEchelon/library).

I've been using last.fm for years but the iTunes-integrated device scrolling simply doesn't work the vast majority of the time which is an issue because I use my iPhone to listen to music at least 50 % of the time.

Comment: I'm even wondering whether iOS provides such API for a third-party application to track what you listened in the Music app. The [last.fm API](https://www.last.fm/api) is the easy part.

Comment: @FranklinYu Probably not but I kind of meant via iTunes as last.fm used to and is supposed to do.